# Dremel 3D45 does not honor temperature settings

Tags: ultimaker-cura, petg, dremel-3d45

I set:

- G-code override: `false`
- filament: PETG
- nozzle temperature: 245 °C

Here the pictures that state the above points:

[image]
[image]

When loading the model, it also confirms the nozzle temperature of 245 °C:

[image]

But when running, it uses another temperature (230 °C) that is even different of what the G-code contains:

[image]

Why? What is my mistake?

---

If the "prioritize G-code" flag is on, the machine would follow the `M104` and `M109` commands contained in the G-code. If true, the machine uses the default filament settings as per the above image.

Comment: Try using your own gcode, printing a single line or simply moving on x and y btw different nozzle temp, and see what happens.I would try this. Check if Cura doesn't add some post-processing code too, sometimes we forgot to remove/disable them.